# Datagridview column is not accepting space value in Window forms

Tags: c#, forms, datetime, events, datagridview

I am working with a Datagridview and I have 5 columns (3 columns accept the only date). For one column, I am using the `CellValidating` event and wrote this code:

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
{             
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)  
    {
        if (datagridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) 
             return;

        String data = e.FormattedValue.ToString();

        if (data != string.Empty)
        {                        
            String validate = @"(0[1-9]|1[012])[/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](19|20)\d\d";
            Regex nameAlphabet = new Regex(validate);
            String nameGridView = data;

            if (!(nameAlphabet.IsMatch(nameGridView)))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Please follow MM/dd/yyyy format to insert date.");
            }
            else
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

This column accepts 'MM/dd/yyyy' format but when I am passing blank space and debug the code, the debugger is not going inside the above code but after that, I got below error.

[image: Datagridview default error dialog]

Please advise I am not getting the right solution for this.

Comment: How is this column defined?

Comment: You have to parse the text input to a DateTime.  I do not think the exception is occurring on posted code..

Comment: @jdweng I think issue is not DateTime parsing, but a missed breakpoint stop.

Comment: @EdoardoChiabra : Read the exception which clearly says the issue is the DataTime parsing from a string.

Comment: I suspect the change event is running before the OP types the full DateTime string so you are getting errors.

Comment: @jdweng Right, but it is not what she's asking.

Comment: @EdoardoChiabra : Yes it is.  She is asking when a space occurs in the Date it is failing. Suppose the Date is : "11/9/2020 11:00PM"and she is getting an exception when the space is typed between the day and hours.

Comment: @jdweng and just after what you copied: "the debugger is not going inside the above code"

Comment: With a space, you data is not null or empty, so the validation is not performed and the edit is not canceled, hence the error is handled *somewhere else*. Remove this condition: `if (data != string.Empty)` and use `DateTime.TryParseExact(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime result)` instead of the Regex.

Comment: If I am entering date it is working fine but when I entered space it shows me this error and I debug the code as well. When CellValidating Event ends then It through this error.

Comment: As already mentioned, this condition: `if (data != string.Empty)` doesn't allow the validation, since a string that contains a space is not empty. Remove it.

Comment: @Jimi This column can accept a date or nothing. I used this: if (data != string.Empty) because I want to make sure the user can not enter the wrong value and columns accept only 'MM/dd/yyyy' format.

Comment: A space is not *nothing*, it's a space, a char like any other. Change your condition in `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString())) { // validate }`. A User can enter a null DateTime leaving the Cell empty (completely empty). In this case the validation is not performed and the DGV will accept the empty value.